# Is there any way to restrict the duration of output of AVAssetWriter in iOS?

Tags: avfoundation, replaykit

I'm capturing video/audio samples using ReplayKit apis. Below is the snippet for capturing screen frames

```
        recorder.startCapture(handler: {
        (cmSampleBuffer, rpSampleBufferType, error) in
        AssetWriter.shared.write(buffer: cmSampleBuffer, bufferType: rpSampleBufferType)
    }, completionHandler: {
        (error) in
        if let error = error {
            self.isCapturing = false
            NSLog("Error in capturing screens: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            self.isCapturing = true
            NSLog("Capturing started successfully.")
        }
        self.updateViewButtons()
    })
```

and converting those cmSampleBuffers using AVAssetWriter to a movie file, but I want to restrict the size of movie file say 1 min if it goes beyond then it capture last 1 min only.

Comment: did you find any solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

The tricky part is 'keeping the last 1min only'; to my knowledge, there is no easy way to do this. So your best bet will probably be something like:

- while recording, start a new AVAssetWriter each minute, and keep just the current and the previous recording around
- when recording is finished and it comes to assembling that 'last 1 minute'

  - open the previous and current recording as `AVAssets`
  - insert time ranges from these into a new `AVMutableComposition` so that they result in this last 1 minute of recording
  - export the composition with an `AVAssetExportSession` to the final movie (using the passthrough preset will spare you the overhead/quality loss of re-encoding)